# Reordering string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have the following function executed as my datatable initiates. It grabs all the keywords in the column "keywords", counts them, and then lists them.

What I want to know is how can I sort the final `counts` variable by value *before* I pass it to the html.

```
function getTags(table) {

var data = $('#mytable').DataTable().rows({search: 'applied'}).data();

var keys=[]; // Get keywords
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  keys.push(data[i].keyword)
}   

var keyStr = keys.toString().split(","); // Split keywords

var keyStr = keyStr.filter(function(n){ return n != "" });  // Filter empty      

var counts = {}; // Count unique
for (var i = 0; i < keyStr.length; i++) {
  counts[keyStr[i]] = 1 + (counts[keyStr[i]] || 0);
}

$.each(counts, function (key,value) { // Print list   
  $("#tags ul").append("<li>" + value + key + "</li>");
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting javascript object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use `Array.prototype.sort()`.

```
counts.sort();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: In this case there's an error: `TypeError: counts.sort is not a function. (In 'counts.sort()', 'counts.sort' is undefined)` . I think it has to do with counts not being an array, but I'm not sure? I added it before `$.each`

Comment: What is counts then? Can what if you change the declaration to var counts= [];

Comment: If I do that, then it returns absolutely nothing.

Comment: It looks like `counts` is a single object with multiple attributes.  Maybe you should sort the array before counting: `var keyStr = keyStr.filter(function(n){ return n != "" }).sort();`

Comment: That improves the overall sorting, but the fact is, only `counts` produces the `value` I want to sort the list by. Does this make sense? Only after `counts` do I know how many times do I have keyword X.

Comment: I see, you want to sort by the count value not the name.  In that case I think the best option is to take your `counts` object and convert it to an array of objects that can then be sorted by the value.  This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11352763/7764175) looks like a good option to me.